# IJulia fails with precompiling LoadError

Tags: julia, conda, using, ijulia-notebook

I have installed Julia 1.5.3 on Ubuntu but IJulia falis with LoadError as shown in the screenshot.

The first path to the conda environment is very wrong, this is running on Ubuntu. The path shown below Precompliling is a WINDOWS path.

Where in the scripts can I correct this reference and allow IJulia to install ?

[image]

Comment: Please replace screenshot with the text - this question does not conform to SO rules.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have had an Anaconda installation that is not available anymore yet your paths are pointing to it. The best thing to do is to install an Anaconda inside Julia. This also works best in practice.

```
using Pkg
ENV["PYTHON"]=""
Pkg.add("PyCall")
Pkg.build("PyCall")
Pkg.add("Conda")
using Conda
Conda.runconda(`install jupyter --yes`) 
Pkg.build("IJulia")
```

Now your code will work.

```
using IJulia
notebook(dir=".")
```

Remember also to try Pluto `Pkg.add("Pluto")` - a new generation of notebooks for Julia.